# Screensaver in C++ with fading image

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp, fade, screensaver

How can I make a screensaver in C++ that fades an image in and out at random places on the screen with a specified time delay on the fade out?

Multimonitor support would be awesome.

If you have a working code or know where I can get it, it would be great. Otherwise point me in the right direction. I'm looking for a method that has a smooth and not laggy og flickery fade. The screensaver is for Windows XP.

I dont know C++, but I do know AS3, Javascript, and PHP. So I was hoping to relate some of that knowledge to C++.

What should I use to compile it?

Comment: Beyond the basics of a screen saver, you'll need some imaging capabilities too.  This is not something I'd wish on someone as a beginning C++ project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off if you're starting out in C++, don't start with a windows specific compiler like visual c++.  Grab a nice cross-platform IDE that comes with a compiler like eclipse or [code::blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads).  Like any project, you are going to want to split it up into smaller tasks you can complete in stages.  Sounds like you have a couple of hurdles.

1. Lack of C++ Knowledge (we were all here once)
2. Lack of knowledge about images (very common affliction)
3. Lack of experience (we'll work on this)

DO NOT let others discourage you.  You CAN do this, and probably faster than you think possible.  DO read a book or two about C++, you can get by for one project without knowing much but you WILL get frustrated often.  Let's break up your project into a set of small goals.  As you complete each goal your confidence in C++ will rise.

1. Image blending
2. Windows Screen Saver w/ multi-monitor support
3. Screen Canvas (directx, opengl, bitmaps?)
4. Timers

First, let's look at the problem of image blending.  I assume that you'll want to "fade" the image in question into whatever windows background you have active.  If you're going to have a solid-color background, you can just do it by changing the alpha transparency of the image in question between canvas refreshes.  Essentially you'll want to average the color values of each pixel in the two images based on your refresh timer.  In more direct terms to find the red, green, and blue pixel elements for any resultant pixel (P3)

N = timer ticks per interval (seconds/milliseconds/etc)
T = ticks that have occurred this interval
P1r = red pixel element from image 1
P2r = red pixel element from image 2
P3r = resultant red pixel element for blended image
P1g = green pixel element from image 1
P2g = green pixel element from image 2
P3g = resultant green pixel element for blended image
P1b = blue pixel element from image 1
P2b = blue pixel element from image 2
P3b = resultant blue pixel element for blended image

```
P3r = ((T/N * P1r) + ((N-T)/N * P2r))/2
P3g = ((T/N * P1g) + ((N-T)/N * P2g))/2
P3b = ((T/N * P1b) + ((N-T)/N * P2b))/2
```

Now let's look at the problem of windows screen savers and multi-monitor support.  These are really two separate problems.  Windows screensavers are really only regular .exe compiled files with a certain callback function.  You can find many tutorials on setting up your screensaver functions on the net.  Multi-monitor support will actually be a concern when you set up your Screen Canvas, which we'll discuss next.

When I refer to the Screen Canvas, I am referring to the area upon which your program will output visual data.  All image rendering apps or tutorials will basically refer to this same concept.  If you find this particularly interesting, please consider a graduate program or learning course in Computer Vision.  Trust me you will not regret it.  Anyway, considering the basic nature of your app I would reccommend against using openGL or DirectX, just because each have their own layer of app-specific knowledge you'll need to acquire before they are useful.  On the other hand if you want built-in 3d niceties like double buffering and gpu offloading, I'd go with openGL (more platform agnostic).  Lots of fun image libraries come as gimmes as well.

As for multi monitor support, this is a tricky but not complicated issue.  You're basically just going to set your canvas bounds (screen boundary) to match the geometry of your multiple monitors.  Shouldn't be an issue with multiple monitors of the same resolution, may get tricky with mismatched monitor resolutions (might have canvas areas not displayed on screen etc.  There are well known algorithms and workarounds for these issues, but perhaps this is beyond the scope of this question.

Finally as to the timers required, this should be the easiest part.  Windows and Linux handle time in their own strange ways (WHY doesn't MS implement STRPTIME), so If you are interested in portability I'd use a 3rd party library.  Otherwise just use the windows settimer() basic functionality and have your image rendered in the callback function.

Advanced Topic:  Hey if you're still reading there are a number of interesting algorithmic improvements you can make to this program.  For instance, with your timer going off a set quanta each second, you could cache the first few blended images and save some processing time (our eyes are not terribly good at noticing differentiating between changing color gradients).  If you are using openGL, you could cache sets of blended images as display lists (gotta use all that graphics card memory for something right?).  Fun stuff, good luck!

Answer (score 5):

> "I dont know C++, but I do know AS3, Javascript, and PHP. So I was hoping to relate some of that knowledge to C++."

Oh boy, I suppose you're going to be surprised. To learn C++:

- Buy at least one or two very good books (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427280/1427737#1427737)). Do not buy books that aren't very good. They'll teach you habits that you would have to unlearn later in order to make further progress.
- Expect having to do plenty of hands-on code writing with a lot of reading in between. In the first few weeks, the compiler will spit legions of incomprehensible error messages at you, your code will keep crashing, and seasoned C++ programmers looking at your code will throw up their hands in disgust. And it's *always* your fault.
- Plan a lot of time to learn. And I mean *a real lot*. No matter how much time you devote, it will take at least a couple of months until you upgrade from "dummy" to "novice".
- Imagine having to hammer at it for a couple of years in order to become a real professional, constantly reading books and articles, devoting plenty of time to newsgroups and discussion forums, learning from others, banging your head against every wall surrounding your desk.
- Be prepared to learn something you haven't known before at least once every week even after a decade of programming in C++ for a living.
- Just for a moment, imagine I might not overstate this.

*Edit for clarification*: I have up-voted both Hunter Davis' and Elemental's answers, because they're very good, pretty much to the point, and in general the encouragement is supported by me despite my rant up there. In fact, I do not doubt that many are able to hack something together in C/C++ when given a skeleton example even if actually they don't know much of C++. Go ahead and try, there's a good chance you'll come up with a screen saver within reasonable time. But. Being able to "hack something together in C/C++" is far from "having learned C++". (And I mean *very* far.)

C++ is an incredible complex, mean, and stubborn beast. I also consider it almost breathtakingly beautiful, but in that it probably mirrors the view from a very high mountain: It's pretty hard to get to the point where you're able to appreciate the beauty.

Comment: Seconded.  It's an incredibly rewarding journey up the mountain, but you're going to be covered in sweat when you get there.  Good Luck!
>C++ is an incredible complex, mean and stubborn beast. I also >consider it almost breathtakingly beautiful, but in that it probably >mirrors the view from a very high mountain: It's pretty hard to get >to the point where you're able to appreciate the beauty.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a complex language and all that sbi indicates is probably true (certainly after 10 years of commercial C++ programming there is still some to learn) BUT I think that if you are confident in another language it should only take a couple of days to:
a) Install one of the compilers mentioned here (I would suggest VC as a quick in to windows programming)
b) Find some sample code of a screen saver that does something simple using the windows GDI (there is some code within the MS documentation on screen savers)
c) Modify this code to do what you want.

In terms of your limited requirement I think you will find that the window GDI++ libraries have sufficient power to do the alpha fades you require smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at microsoft c++ express. It's free and pretty capable. You may need to hack it, or get an older version, to produce unmanaged executables.

There are a lot of [tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+windows+screen+saver) available for the rest